# Chrome Extension, chrome.notification not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

We're developing a web extension. We're actually trying to add some functionalities on the extension such as notifications.
For instance, we don't see any notifications at all, not even in the log console and we can't figure out the problem.
Do you have any ideas ?
Here is our manifest and our background.
Thank you in advance.

```
{

  "description": "truc écolo",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "PolNum",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon48.png"
  },
  
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "activeTab",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "tabs",
  "*://*.google.com/",
  "storage",
  "alarms",
  "history",
  "notifications" 
],

"browser_action": {
  "default_popup" :"popup.html",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon32.png"
    }
  },

"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }  
}





chrome.notifications.create('test', {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: "icons/icon16N.png",
    title: 'Test Message',
    message: 'You are awesome!',
    priority: 2
});
```

Comment: 1) Make sure to open the [correct console](/a/10258029). 2) It may be a bug in Chrome e.g. https://crbug.com/825497.